# PDO named parameter problems

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have worked with PHP 5.x and MySQL, but now, I would love to switch to PDO because of higher recommended PHP version.

My database has 398 entries, one with interpret (artist) "Joe Cocker" and I wanted to select that row. But the query always lists ALL rows!

Why?

Here's what I did as a test:

```
$request = "Joe Cocker";
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM jdf_xxx WHERE interpret LIKE :interpret");
$statement->execute(array('interpret' => "%$request%"));   
while ($row = $statement->fetch()) 
{
    $count++;
    $inter = $row['interpret'];
    $title = $row['titel'];
    $trackid = $row['folge'];
    $datum = strftime("%d. %B %Y", $row['datum']);
}
```

By the way, no problem with the login to the database (seperate file!) and my old query with MySQL and PHP worked fine.
Any help?

Comment: Show us you database connection code please

Comment: <?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
    ?>
I use include in my script! It works fine!

Comment: I just wanted to see what parameters you had set, or in this case had not set

Comment: I added the missing colon and it works now, thanks

Comment: You have not set PDO to throw exceptions, so you need to check for errors in your code. **After the execute add** `if ( !$statement){ print_r($statement->errorInfo()); exit;}`

Comment: ok thanks, but where do I have to add it? After the while loop?

Comment: No like I said, after the **`->execute`** and on all calls to execute. Woudl be better to set `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` as part of your connection code. [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Comment: ok thanks, I got it - and I was asked to avoid extended discussions and I'm new and can't open a chat....thanks again for your help